# Массив дат из CarbonPeriod

Tags: php, carbon

всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как в моем случае получить массив c датами с 2018-06-14 по 2018-06-20?

```html
$period = CarbonPeriod::create('2018-06-14', '2018-06-20');


        
foreach ($period as $date) {
    $date->format('Y-m-d');
}


сейчас у меня вот так

dd($date->format('Y-m-d'));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($period as $date) {
    $date->format('Y-m-d');
    $array[] = $date;
  }
print_r($array);
```

Comment: да то что нужно! но только подскажите подалуйста как причесать в массиве карбоновские даты в необходимом мне виде? обновил первый пост

Comment: dd($date->format('Y-m-d')); выводит в нужном формате, но в массив нето добавилось

Comment: а все разобрался

Answer (score 3):

фрагмент из [мануала](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-period)

```
$dates = $period->map(function (Carbon $date) {
                       return $date->format('Y-m-d');
                   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно ещё так:

```
 $period->toArray();
```